# Using pyuno on MacOS to do file conversions

Tags: python, macos, openoffice.org, uno, pyuno

I am running MacOS 10.6 and OpenOffice 3.3.  I am interested in using PyUNO to script conversions of .odp to .ppt, .pdf, and .swf.  I have not found any clear documentation on how to do so with MacOS.  Does anyone know of existing documentation to get the process going?  I am fairly proficient in python, but I can't even find how to access the language bindings on MacOS.  Any pointers?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they have fixed the issue, but as of a couple months ago you could not run pyUNO scripts outside of OOo on a MAC.  See the article: ["Shall we ship OOo with internal python on Mac?"](http://www.mail-archive.com/mac@porting.openoffice.org/msg03558.html)

Comment: The latest LibreOffice4 ships with a Python 3.2 installation which works fine.  Unfortunately, this then duplicates the existing MacPorts Python install, and installing UNO on a MacPorts Python hasn't worked yet.